# How to get the remaining time after which worker will do work?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, androidx, android-workmanager

I schedule one time work in 100 minutes:

```
val request = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorker().setInitialDelay(100, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build()
WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniqueWork(
    "MY_WORKER_NAME",
    ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
    request
)

class MyWorker(context: Context, workerParameters: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(
    context, workerParameters) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
       return Result.success()
}
```

How can I get the remaining time, before `doWork()` is executed?
For example, I need to know it immediately after I reboot my Android device

Comment: I do not think that there is an API for that. Partly, that is because with other conditions, it may not be knowable when the work will run (e.g., if you require network access or being on a charger).

Comment: There is no API.